# BizTalk Send Port OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

I have a BizTalk solution deployed at a customer site.
(BizTalk 2006 R2 with the non WCF adapters)
One of the orchestrations issues an RFC call to a SAP system and returns a big message.
The message is mapped to a SQL Adapter Send Port schema which is calling a stored procedure.

Recently I'm running into a OutOfMemory exception when the message is sent to the SQL Adapter.
I did a trace with SQL profiler which resulted in a 90MB+ tracefile for just a few seconds.
As I imagined, the Stored Procedure is executed rapidly one after another.

But even this does not explain why I get the error message. The Server has 32GB RAM and I can't even see it peaking out...

Any suggestions what else I could check?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at how much memory the host of the Send Port is configured to use? 32GB of memory is irrelevant if the host is not set to take advantage of it. That being said, I think the default is 25% of the available memory. So barring any change this may not be the problem.

You could also try playing with the throttling settings for the host. Although I have never had much luck with it myself.

One way to get more information is to hook up Perfmon and look at the memory around that specific host process.